# Failed to collect page data using Expo with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, expo

I am currently trying to build my application using `yarn next build`. However, it will fail after attempting to collect page data from `react-native\index.js` because of an import issue with `AccessibilityInfo`, which results in the common `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Afterwards it will attempt collection for `/calculator` and it will result in the same error.

I have tried double-checking the transpiled packages and all my RN import seems to be in correct order, but I am too unknowledgeable to confirm anything sadly.

Both **Next.config.js** and **package.json** are below and if there's anything else needed to probably find the culprit, I will upload it aswell.

Thankfully, all these frustrations really helps growing and thank you for reading (and/or) helping!

**ERROR**

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data ..C:\Users\S\Documents\Projects\Sundberegn\node_modules\react-native\index.js:14
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1094:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1129:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\S\Documents\Projects\Sundberegn\node_modules\react-native-fit-image\dist\FitImage.js:24:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /calculator
    at C:\Users\S\Documents\Projects\Sundberegn\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:963:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**Next.config.js**

```js
const { withExpo } = require("@expo/next-adapter");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = withExpo(
    {
        reactStrictMode: true,
        swcMinify: true,
        transpilePackages: [
            "react-native",
            "expo",
            "expo-linear-gradient",
            "expo-font",
            "react-native-svg",
            "lucide-react-native",
            "prop-types",
            "react-native-markdown-display",
            
            // Add more React Native / Expo packages here...
        ],
        experimental: {
            forceSwcTransforms: true,
        },
    },
    withFonts({
        projectRoot: __dirname,
    }),
);

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.115.0",
    "next": "~13.1.1",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@expo/next-adapter": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "next dev",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "sundberegn"
}
```